# MVC3 date calculation as added date

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datetime

I am trying to handle dateTime. I have created dateCreated field which is using Now(). Could I add other calculated dateTime field, which is added two days automatically.
For example, dateCreated is created on 18th March 2012. I want to create new dateTime value which set on 20th March 2012. Is it possible to calculate date in model?
Here is my code. Thanks.

```
public class Cart
{
    [Key]
    public int recordId { get; set; }
    public string cartId { get; set; }
    public int productId { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateCreated { get; set; }
    // Can I make startDate as adding two days with dateCreated?
    // Is there any calculation for this?
    //public DateTime startDate { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var startdate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private DateTime _startDate;


public DateTime StartDate
{
  set { _startDate=value; }
  get { return dateCreated.AddDays(2); }

}
```